# How can I solve this error "Does not allow NULL, Insert Aborted"?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to call a stored procedure to make an insert:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=**********;Integrated Security=True";

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString: connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertAngajat", sqlCon))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nume", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Prenume", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DataNasterii", SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox4.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DataAngajare", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cnp", SqlDbType.Char).Value = textBox3.Text.ToCharArray();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Localitate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox8.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Judet", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox10.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Strada", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox9.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Departament", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Telefon", SqlDbType.Char).Value = textBox5.Text.ToCharArray();

            if (checkBox1.Checked) 
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.Char).Value = 'M';
            else if (checkBox2.Checked) 
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sex", SqlDbType.Char).Value = 'F';
            else 
                MessageBox.Show("Nu a fost bifat sexul");

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Numar", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Salariu", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);

            sqlCon.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    this.Close();  
}
```

But this is the error I get when I press the button and save everything.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTntF.png

This is the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertAngajat] 
    @Nume VARCHAR(50), 
    @Prenume VARCHAR(50),
    @Departament VARCHAR(50),
    @cnp CHAR(13),
    @DataNasterii DATE,
    @Telefon VARCHAR(12) = "NONE",
    @DataAngajare DATE,
    @Salariu INT,
    @Sex CHAR(1) = 'F',
    @Judet VARCHAR(50),
    @Localitate VARCHAR(50),
    @Strada VARCHAR(50),
    @Numar INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @DepID INT = (SELECT D.DepartamentID 
                          FROM Departamente D 
                          WHERE D.[Nume Departament] = @Departament);

    INSERT INTO [dbo].Angajat (Nume, Prenume, DepartamentID, CNP, DataNasterii,
                               Telefon, DataAngajarii, Salariu, Sex, Localitate,
                               [Sector/Judet], Strada, nr)
    VALUES (@Nume, @Prenume, @DepID, @cnp, @DataNasterii,
            @Telefon, @DataAngajare, @Salariu, @Sex, @Localitate,
            @Judet, @Strada, @Numar)        
END
```

I made sure that the text boxes were having data. I have no idea what else to try.

I'm expecting that as long as the values in the text boxes aren't `NULL` to be able to Insert all their data easily.

Comment: Please include the full exception as _text_ in your question.

Comment: I mean, the most likely cause is that the value in combobox1 doesn't exist in the Departamente table, so when you try to populate the @DepID variable it gets set to null.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is use a breakpoint in your code and inspect all variable values right before `ExecuteNonQuery` and see if there any NULL values. Debugging and inspection is the very first thing you need to learn if you want to solve issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that your issue probably lies with this line:

```
Declare @DepID int = (Select D.DepartamentID From Departamente D Where D.[Nume Departament] = @Departament);
```

What happens if there are no results for this query? I'm a bit rusty, but I imagine `@DepId` will be `NULL`. Then when you try and insert it into your table, you're inserting a null.

Solution: Either in your procedure, or before calling the insert, check if the department exists.

Comment: I agree that's the likely cause.  One reason this could be non-obvious is that @Department is `VARCHAR` and the .NET client using Unicode (NVARCHAR).  The problem might be a conversion there failing to match up exactly (accents etc.).

Comment: @LoztInSpace I'd completely forgotten about that :) Hopefully OP will be back to clarify.

Comment: The problem was that my @DepID was NULL because I had the values in my table differ from the ones in my combobox. I really have to sop codding at 4AM. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Run your sql profiler and trace the call. So that, you will be sure about your all input parameters. And then execute your procedure call manually. You will be able to find the exact issue and the line in the procedure. Try one with fixed value of @DepID int=1. If it's running successfully. Then you have to optimized this line of code as below:
Declare @DepID int = (Select isnull(D.DepartamentID,0) From Departamente D Where D.[Nume Departament] = @Departament);

It seems your Departamente  table don't have data for this department.